# Output a string of arrays, wrapped in characters (That make a box) using process.argv

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to Box a List of Words in The CLI using node and process.argv

```
var topLeftCorner = "┏"
var line = "━"
```

and etc characters to make the parts of the border

```
function drawTopBorder(number) {
    return topLeftCorner + line.repeat(number) + topRightCorner;
}

function drawBarsAround(name) {
    return leftLine + name + " ".repeat(longest.length - name.length) + rightLine
}
```

and etc functions to create the box from the borders

```
//find longest string in array which will be max-width of box
var lgth = 0;
var longest;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > lgth) {
        var lgth = arr[i].length;
        longest = arr[i];
    }
```

So that is where I am at now. I ended up trying to use .forEach() but that wrapped each individual string in a box, while I am trying to make the box join together to to speak.

Expected functionality:

```
node boxit.js 'Jon Snow' 'Cersei Lannister' 'Daenerys Targaryen'
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃Jon Snow          ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃Cersei Lannister  ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃Daenerys Targaryen┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Comment: A good place to start is to figure out what `number` should be. Perhaps the length of the longest string in the array...

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks. Number will come from the length of each process.argv followed node
eg
John will make "━━━━"

Comment: @MarkMeyer that definitely got me going in the right direction but I am still stumped. Editted question

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below. You need to establish the padding required in column 1 which I've done as the max width of column 1 per the longest item in the array (Daenerys) less the length of the current item to be output. The width of column 2 is fixed here. Once you know the max widths of both columns you can calculate the length of the separating line.

```js
// input array
var a = ['Jon Snow', 'Cersei Lannister', 'Daenerys Targaryen'];

// column widths
var col1Max = Math.max(...(a.map(i => i.length)));
var col2Max = 10;
var tableWidth = col1Max + col2Max + 3;

// line separator
var separator = '_'.repeat(tableWidth);

// formatting function
function output(item, end) {
 // calculate padding
  var pad = col1Max - item.length;
  var formattedItem = `|${item}${' '.repeat(pad)}|${' '.repeat(col2Max)}|` 
  // output
  console.log(separator);
  console.log(formattedItem);
  if (end) console.log(separator);
}

// iterate array
for (let i=1; i<=a.length; i++) {
 output(a[i-1], i == a.length);
}
```

Comment: Hi there appreciate it

Comment: Feel free to check the green tick if it's the right answer for you